# android: communication with PC desktop app and remote mediaplayer controller

Tags: android, http, android-wifi, remote-server

Dont get angry on me please. I have two questions, I think on very similar theme, so I decided to merge them into one. I have my app on android that is using sensors to do some calculations. I am storing there sesults in my database. What i want to do is to send my data from my phone to my desktop app  also with a database (on button click).

To be more precise, here is an example: My light sensor reads current light intensity. Lets say it is 1000lux. Now, when I click my button "Send" in my android app, it will send this value to my desktop apps database. That desktop app will read that value and will show it to user.

Is it possible via WIFI? or better via web, so i will not be limited with distance? 
How can android manage this kind of communication?

And my second question is, if controlling media player on my PC is similar to what i said.

EDIT:

I did some research and found one Socket tutorial. I tried it exactly like it is there. So i have this in my android app:

```
public class Client extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_client);
    Client myCli = new Client();
    try {
        myCli.run();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_client, menu);
    return true;
}


public void run() throws Exception {

    Socket mySkt = new Socket("192.168.1.6", 9999);

     PrintStream myPS = new PrintStream(mySkt.getOutputStream());

     myPS.println("Hello server");

     BufferedReader myBR = new BufferedReader
    (new InputStreamReader(mySkt.getInputStream()));


}
```

}

and this in netBeans:

```
//Author: WarLordTech
//Website: http://www.youtube.com/user/WarLordTech
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Server {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
      Server myServ = new Server();
      myServ.run();
  }

  public void run() throws Exception{
      ServerSocket mySS = new ServerSocket(9999);
      Socket SS_accept = mySS.accept();

      BufferedReader SS_BF= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader
        (SS_accept.getInputStream()));

      String temp = SS_BF.readLine();
      System.out.println(temp);

      if (temp!=null) {
        PrintStream SSPS = new PrintStream(SS_accept.getOutputStream());
        SSPS.println("Got something");
      }
   }
}
```

It still isnt workiong. Do I have to set up my network somehow?

Comment: Did you find an answer for this? Your edit answer looks correct. What was the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using TCP Sockets. Many languages have implementations for Socket programming so you would "need" to program your desktop app in Java (of course that is always possible!).

[Socket Tutorial in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/index.html)

This would work over the net and local wifi. You could use other methods for local wifi such as a UDP connection. You'd need to setup a TCP server and make sure you had access etc.

There may be other ways to do this but it's not such a trivial task to do!

Comment: Thank you for your help. That is for my desktop app, but what do i have to do with my android app? Is this applicable also to android?

Comment: Yep, same thing - If you are writing your app in Java, then it can use sockets. Then it just uses whatever data connection you have on your phone device, ie wifi, 3g to connect.